# How to add type-specific code for generics in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics

Is there any efficient way to add type specific code for delphi generics ?
For example something like this:

```
function TGT<T>.GetSize(a: T): integer;
begin
  {$IF TypeInfo(T)=TypeInfo(String)}
    result := Length(A);
  {$ELSE}
    result := SizeOf(A);
  {$IFEND}
end;

function TGT<T>.Compare(a,b: T): integer;
begin
  {$IF TypeInfo(T)=TypeInfo(String)}
    result := AnsiCompareText(a,b);
  {$ELSE}
    result := a-b;
  {$IFEND}
end;
```

So i need to implement some parts of the code in different ways depending on type.
For example if i implement Sort routine i would like to use direct comparison of values of integer/double/etc types (it is more efficient than calling of interface methods like delphi's standard generic containers do) and function AnsiCompareText for String type.

There some examples how to do it, but all of them based on check like this:

```
if TypeInfo(T)=TypeInfo(String) then xxx else if TypeInfo(T)=TypeInfo(Integer) then xxx
```

Problem here is that Delphi will check it in run-time only, that is (again) not so efficient. 
I would like to make compiler to do all checks in compile-time and use only code specific for selected type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you certainly cannot hope to do anything like that with conditional compilation. Remember that conditional compilation for generics are handled in the generic compilation phase rather than the instantiation phase. And so you cannot expect different instantiations to be compiled with different branches of your conditional statement.

And you certainly can never get the compiler to accept `Length(a)` where the type of `a` is parametrised, because there is no way to specify a constraint that would allow the use of `Length`.

The only option is a run-time check.

Comment: I understand that conditional compilation doesn't solve my problem, i used it only for illustration. But i hope some another way exists. In all Delphi's generics i saw, interfaces where used to accomplish type-specific tasks. And it doesn't look like solid and clear concept, it looks like kind of hack or trick. It seems strange to introduce such powerfull tool like generics, but without ability to make code efficient. Actually it means that for time critical tasks, even in such common routines like sorting of data, it will be more efficient to copy-paste code instead of using generics.

Comment: Are you quite sure that using the generic comparer interfaces in Generics.Defaults is really that slow? Anyway, generics are not templates. They inherently are less capable than templates.

Comment: @David, I recently read a lot from you about a "Generic compilation phase". Although this makes a lot of sense to me, is this documented somewhere ?

Comment: @iamjoosy I don't think so. I made up that term when writing an answer, this one I think! There are various Emba blogs that talk about the different compilation phases.

Comment: @iamjoosy Here's the best link I can find: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/10/01/38465/

Comment: Just finished small test (ordering of 10 millions of random doubles):
copy-pasted qsort - 1872 ms
TList<double>.Sort- 4368 ms
Disappointing...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for the link to Craig's article, very interesting read ! Am I right with my conclusion, that a dcu with Generics in it is not compiled to machine code, but rather to the syntax tree of that code ? What about mixed Generic / non Generic units ? hmm, maybe I should better ask a question about this.

Comment: @iamjoosy Generic types are compiled to an intermediate AST state and then each specialization results in standard code gen

Comment: @David, that of course explains why each Generic class instantiation creates a new class, which sometimes leads to some surprises - think of class vars e.g.

Comment: Article is really interesting. It describes how generics implemented in Delphi, at least some details. Indeed generics are limited not because of such implementation, but probably just because it was decided implement them limited. AST is just another presentation of source code and don’t limit usage of it in any form. What DCU real machine code comes (DCU with generic compiled or DCU where generic used/instantiated with real type) also is not so important. But anyway we have what we have...